# How can I combine a list in for loop with a variable name? (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop

I am not sure the question title is right. But what I am trying to do is to combine one of the lists in for loop into a variable name.

Also, I would like to substitute Korean list into english name when it is selected to run.

I hope my result will show:

```
아우디, ['A1', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']
bmw, ['1시리즈', '2시리즈', '3시리즈', '4시리즈']
벤츠, ['A클래스', 'B클래스', 'C클래스', 'E클래스']
```

Below is my code:

```
manufacturers = ['아우디', 'bmw', '벤츠']

#아우디 = audi
#벤츠 = benz

preset_models_audi = ['A1', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']
preset_models_bmw = ['1시리즈', '2시리즈', '3시리즈', '4시리즈']
preset_models_benz = ['A클래스', 'B클래스', 'C클래스', 'E클래스']

for manufacturer in manufacturers:
    print (manfacturer, preset_models_???)
```

Comment: You need to use another container and iterate over that as well...

Comment: I figured out. Thanks.